# '97 dodge grand caravan won't start - sometimes

Tags: electrical

intermitent won't start problem. Might start when I turn key a couple extra times or a 1000 times, til my fingers are sore. Sometimes I have to leave it and come back later, but sometimes I'm a ways from home. Just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Does it start after you wiggle the gear lever?

Answer (score 1):

Need more info, define "won't start"...  Does it crank, but not fire?  No cranking?

Common generic (I don't know anything specific about Dodge Grand Caravans) causes include: Bad coil, power transistor/ignitor, ignition switch, broken ground...

Comment: We definitely need more information, but I'd like to add I had an issue with my 97 caravan not starting.

The distributor cap was cracked, and it would crank but not fire if there was lots of moisture in the air (humid, or the car got rained on.)

Just needed a replacement.